# Why does allowableValues lead to invalid OpenAPI JSON?

Tags: java, openapi-generator

```
@Schema(allowableValues = { "A", "B" })
private List<String> types;
```

leads to

```
"types": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
            "A",
            "B"
        ]
    },
    "enum": [
        "A",
        "B"
    ]
},
```

but should lead to

```
"types": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
            "A",
            "B"
        ]
    }
},
```

without the second enum at the bottom which will lead to compile errors in generated Java code.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Which tool / plugin did you use to generate the OpenAPI spec: _springdoc-openapi_ or _springfox_ ? Which version of the tool and the OpenAPI are you using ?